# plug light in without spark?

Tags: power, dc, 12v, spark

I have spotlights which go on 12V/24V distributor but every time I plug one in there is a spark, they still do work fine but it's a bit scary and just annoying when all the other ones flicker every time I plug one in (I have 8 spots connected total) and the others flicker when there is arc.

I found they have this plug for rc cars and then they can plug and there is no spark.

https://aliexpress.com/item/32784910994.html

the rating seems okso I guess they work what do you people think? Is it worth doing 16 plugs of them for all the lights and then they would be fine? Or do I just need one of them on the distributor and then nothing can spark?

Comment: What kind of spotlights? Show link to specs

Comment: Is your distributor a battery or a power supply or both?

Answer (score 1):

Anti-spark power supply connectors make the contact in 2 phases

Phase 1: A series resistor allows possible capacitors to get charged less violently. This reduces inrush current peak and the spark when the contact is not established.

Phase 2: The extra series resistor is bypassed to create the final low resistance contact

If your lights have electronic current regulator they quite surely have a capacitor, too. ==> The anti-spark connector can be useful.

What is a good type cannot be solved here without knowing the specs of your lights and the used power source.

If it happens that you use old school halogens, they also take a hefty starting peak when they are cold. If you are unlucky you may burn the connector if you let the series resistor be active too long. Inrush limiter for a halogen must be designed with different specs. The linked ones were made for hobbyist drone batteries.

Every item which is plugged in separately to existing voltage needs its own ant-spark connector because the the resistor works when the connector has already made the 1st touch but is slliding towards the final "connected" -position.